# Android OpenGL Vertex Array or VBO

Tags: android, optimization, opengl-es, vbo

I've done a little opengl programming on android but I'm a little confused on something that k haven't been able to find a clear answer for.

I've read that VBO allocate memory on the GPU and are good for static vertex data and vertex arrays don't allocate the data but copy it for each draw call.

When I use a float buffer on android like shown here http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/04/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-%E2%80%93-part-ii-building-a-polygon/

Is that a VBO or a vertex array?

If I want to modify my vertices every frame what's the best way to do this in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't call `glBufferData` at some point (the tutorial does not), than it's not a VBO.

Using floatBuffers I believe that the data is still held by the opengl client, and not in graphics memory.

This is very important distinction on desktop systems where GPUs have their own onboard memory with much faster access than system RAM. However on Android I guess that the difference will be much less, because it has unified memory (system and video memory are shared).